# how to check if a control of a certain type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use th below code, it works. All the controls are hidden.

```
foreach (Control ctr in eItem.Controls)
{
    ctr.visible = false;                  
}
```

However, I want to hide only labels and dropdownlists. That why I'm trying to use the below code without success

```
foreach (Control ctr in eItem.Controls)
{
    if(ctr is Label | ctr is DropDownList)
    {
       ctr.visible = false;
    }              
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the whole method

```
 private void HideLabelAndDDLOnPageLoad()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem eItem in lsvTSEntry.Items)
        {
            foreach (Control ctr in eItem.Controls)
            {
                if (ctr is Label || ctr is DropDownList)
                {
                    ctr.Visible = false;
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

When I remove the if, all the controls get hidden. When I put it back, nothing happens.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"? What's happening, and what did you want to happen? And why are you using | instead of ||? (You don't *have* to use ||, but it's more idiomatic.)

Comment: @Richard...are you getting an error message?  Please post the error

Comment: I have changed | to ||, there's no error, but all the controls I want to disable are still sitting there.

Comment: @Richard77: If you've got no error, then the code you've posted isn't the code you're running - you should be getting a compile-time error. Please post your *real* code.

Comment: @Jon Sket, I just did. I'm sure it's the code being executed because, when I remove the "if", all the controls get hidden.

Comment: @Richard77: Okay, that's more like it. Now look at my edited answer - I suspect that you don't have Label or DropDownList controls *directly* in ListViewItem.Controls. I suspect you have container controls.

Comment: Could you show the markup for your `ListView` control?

Comment: @Richard77 - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11800117/168703, it appears from your comments that you have controls inside of a content template within an updatepanel.

Comment: As I'm about to delete my answer: The use of `|` instead of `||` is a red herring, although I'd definitely recommend using `||` in general. (The difference here is that `|` isn't short-circuiting. The results in this case will be the same using either operator, as there are no side-effects.) For those answers claiming this is the problem, read section 7.11.3 of the C# spec.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet. This FindControl thing makes me regret Asp.Net MVC

Comment: `FindControl` is not specific to ASP.net MVC, web forms uses that as well, its a fabulous method and does exactly what it says, and that is to find a control.

Comment: @JonH, I meant that I miss Asp.net MVC, because I don't have to worry about FindControl(). It's very annoying this findControl thing. But, thanks for helping perfectly.

Comment: your question doesn't really match your title. You already have `if (ctr is Label)`  So you know full well how to check if an object is of a certain type e.g. of type Label.  If you had an issue with `||` then that should be a very different question title.

Comment: also, another way to check the type of a control is e.g. (and that namespace Windows.Forms.GroupBox that i've used is for a winforms program)  but check the path of whatever control's class  `if (c.GetType()==typeof(System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you are after is `||` change it to `||`...that is the logical or operator.

```
foreach (Control ctr in eItem.Controls)
{
    if(ctr is Label || ctr is DropDownList)
    {
       ctr.Visible = false;
    }              
}
```

`|` = bitwise operator

`||` = logical or operator

## Based on your edit

It appears your controls are inside an `updatepanel`, if that is the case you want to loop for all controls within the updatepanel's content template container.

Here you go:

```
foreach (Control ctr in UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls)
 {
  // rest of code
   if(ctr is Label || ctr is DropDownList)
     {
        ctr.Visible = false;
     }         
 }
```

Comment: Nope, `|` would work fine. It wouldn't short-circuit, but it would work.

Comment: I downvoted - this definitely isn't the problem. It's non-idiomatic, but it's valid code which would give exactly the same results.

Comment: @JonSkeet - fair the result is the same but you have to look at it as to what operator to use for what is being done.  A logical operator here makes sense, your downvote tends to disagree with this, its definately not worth the downvote as no where did I mention it was wrong to use `|` I recommended what should be used.  You are being too critical.

Comment: @JonH: Does your answer help the OP solve their problem? Absolutely not - but it *implies* that it does. If you'd said: "It won't have any effect, but you should use `||` instead of `|` to be idiomatic" then that would have been a different matter - although that would be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @JonH: Yes, that's much more like it.

Answer (score 1):

Without your exact markup we can only guess the solution here.

You must be using another container to wrap your controls inside your ItemTemplate in the ListView, something like a Panel or other containers. When you get the Controls on the list view item you actually get the warping container and not its children(labels, dropdowns etc.)
One solution to this is something like:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lsvTSEntry.Items)
{
    item.FindControl("myLabel").Visible = false;
    item.FindControl("myDropdownList").Visible = false;
}
```

Basically you try to find the controls by id and hide them. Notice there is no error checking there so you could get a NullReferenceException if FindControl returns null.

In case you have nested containers in your ItemTemplate and you want to hide all the labels and dropdowns regardless of where they are you can implement your own recursive FindControl that will look like:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlId)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlId)
    {
        return rootControl;
    }

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlId);
        if (controlToReturn != null)
        {
            return controlToReturn;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Not the most elegant but.... You can change this to take an array of Id's of course for speed purposes.
Based on this of course you can implement the search by control type which instead of taking a controlId as a parameter will take the types of controls to find.

Answer (score 1):

The | is the bitwise or operator.
You are looking for ||, the logical or operator.

```
 if(ctr is Label || ctr is DropDownList)
```

Comment: Definitely not the problem. See my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet That is not worth a downvote.  +1 Marty, readability and correct use of operator is more like it.

Comment: @JonH: The use of `|` is *correct* - it's valid code and the result will be the same. I don't believe this answer (or the other similar ones) are useful to help the OP solve their problem. Comments on code style which don't actually address the question are better *as comments*.